# Transform business object into view model in angular-meteor

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

#### Background

I have an angular-meteor app and a collection of business objects in mongodb, e.g.:

```
{ startDate: new Date(2015, 1, 1), duration: 65, value: 36 }
```

I want to render this data in different views. One of the views is a graph, another is a list of entries.
The list of entries is easy. Just bind the collection to the model:

```
vm.entries = $scope.meteorCollection(MyData, false);
```

In the view I would do:

```
<div ng-repeat="entry in vm.entries">{{entry.startDate}} - ...</div>
```

But now for the graph. I want to transform each element into a `{ x, y }` object and give the view that, e.g.:

```
vm.graphPoints = transformData(getDataHere());
```

The problem is that the data is not fetched here, in angular-meteor is looks like it is fetched when calling the `entry in vm.entries` in the view. The kicker is that the `transformData` method, needs to loop through the data and for each item index into other items to calculate the resulting x, y. Hence I cannot use a simple forEach loop (without having access to the other items in some way).

#### Question

So how can i fetch the data in the controller - transform it - and still have one-way binding (observing) on new data added to the database?

Thanks

#### Update

The following code works, but I think there could be performance problems with fetching the whole collection each time there is a change.

```
$scope.$meteorSubscribe("myData").then(function() {
    $scope.$meteorAutorun(function() {
        var rawData = MyData.find().fetch();
        vm.model.myData = transformData(rawData);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
This is the current solution:

```
$scope.collectionData = $scope.meteorCollection(MyData, false);
$meteor.autorun($scope, function() {
        vm.graphPoints = transformData($scope.collectionData.fetch());
    });
```

There is some missing information. do you wan't to have some kind of model object in the client? if that is correct I think you have to do something like this:

```
$meteor.autorun($scope, function() {
        vm.graphPoints = transformData($scope.meteorCollection(MyData, false));
    });
```

Comment: Yes a transformed client-side model. Your example looks like just the thing I need! Will test tomorrow and let you know.Thanks

Comment: If the works - It might be that it is better to save the collection once and do only the `transformData` in autorun to prevent a leak.

Comment: It works if I do a .fetch() on the collection: `$scope.meteorCollection(MyData, false).fetch()`

Comment: Sorry @oshai my last comment was not working code... I will update the question with the version we got running.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the Collection Helper Meteor package to add the function:
https://github.com/dburles/meteor-collection-helpers/
?

Comment: It looks like I can do custom queries or a transform on each object. But the problem is that I need a transform method for the whole list of objects, not one for each element.